# Hidden UITabBar while UITabBarController is inserted into container view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

For some reason I need to insert `UITabBarController` into conatiner view.

When `UITabBarController` is presented itself (VC with container view is skipped) it works perfectly and everything is being showed. But when I insert it into `UIView` like below `UITabBar` exists in Debug View Hierarchy but it is not visible in the app. In both cases attributtes of UITabBar in object inspector are the same.

```
private var tabBar: TabBarController!
@IBOutlet private var tabBarContainer: UIView! 
...
addChildViewController(tabBar)
tabBarContainer.addSubview(tabBar.view)
tabBar.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Comment: It might be a pretty trivial, but it might be the reason of the issue: Have you checked that `UITabBarController` view has the same frame as the container view frame? (`tabBar.view.frame = view.frame`)

Comment: @AhmadF I think you're right. It's problem with a frame. But take a look at my [Hierarchy Inspector](https://imgur.com/a/kg5FXys). The selected view is the container view and the next one on the stack is TabBarController. As you can see they are not equally placed on the screen. I did tabBar.view.frame = tabBarContainer.frame right before adding child view controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've figured it out.
There are two ways to fix it:

1:

```
addChildViewController(tabBar)
tabBar.view.frame = tabBarContainer.bounds
tabBarContainer.addSubview(tabBar.view)
tabBar.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

2:

```
addChildViewController(tabBar)
tabBarContainer.addSubview(tabBar.view)
tabBar.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tabBarContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
tabBarContainer.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.bottom.equalTo(tabBar.view.snp.bottom)
    make.top.equalTo(tabBar.view.snp.top)
    make.left.equalTo(tabBar.view.snp.left)
    make.right.equalTo(tabBar.view.snp.right)
}
```